# Advanced array structure

Tags: python, arrays, variables

My dictionary has the following structure:

```
a = 'stringA'
b = 'stringB'
c = 'stringC'

endpoints = {
    'foo1': a + 'string1' + b,
    'foo2' : a + 'string2' + c + 'string3' + b,
}
```

My problem is the following: when I call `endpoints['foo2']`, I get the expected array value. However, when I change the value of, for instance, `c` between the array declaration and the usage of `endpoints['foo2']`, the value of `c` is not updated.

Any idea of why this happens and how can it be solved?

PS: I know this could be done creating a simple function, but I think that would be quite more inefficient.

Comment: Thats because your array does not save a reference to `c`

Comment: @JeD There are no arrays here - or at all in python (unless you count numpy arrays and other non-native modules). `endpoints` is a dictionary.

Comment: @Alvaro Gomez *"when I change the value of, for instance, c"*. Try posting the code you use to change the value of `c`

Comment: @jDo I just modify the value with `c='newString'`, but after reading @JeD answer, I see that I have confused myself with Java coding.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​As far as I know, if you don't use `lambda`, then it's impossible since a string can not be changed after you created it in Python (`a + 'string2' + c + 'string3' + b` creates a string huh?).

Comment: @jDo dammit, I always say array when I mean Lists :/ But yeah, my point still stands. By assigning `a` anew endpoints will not be changed.

Comment: @KevinGuan yep Strings are immutable. You can get around it by defining a own class or putting the string into a list.

Comment: @JeD There no lists either :P But yeah, you're right. The values are fixed/immutable as soon as `endpoints` is created and it would take a re-definition of the particular entry to change it. @Alvaro would have to do `c='newString'` followed by `endpoints['foo2'] = a + 'string2' + c + 'string3' + b` or use a lambda function like Kevin Guan suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
a = ['stringA']
b = ['stringB']
c = ['stringC']

endpoints = {
    'foo1': a ,
    'foo2' : b
}

print(endpoints['foo1']) #returns "[stringA]"

a[0]='otherString'

print(endpoints['foo1']) #returns "[otherString]"
```

You can do this, because you can change the values in a list without changing the reference;

`a` and `endpoints` are still using the same space for `a`

This is not possible for pure Strings, because you can not change them without a new assignment. Strings in Python are **immutable**.

Edit: Another possibility would be to create your own string class.

This removes the `[]` brackets:

```
class MyStr:

    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val

    def __repr__(self):
    #this function is called by dict to get a string for the class
        return self.val

    def setVal(self,val):
        self.val=val

a=MyStr("abcd")
b={1:a}
print(b) #prints {1:"abcd"}
a.setVal("cdef")
print(b) #prints {1:"cdef"}
```

Disclaimer: As explained in the comments I am still using python 2.7

While Python 3 and 2.7 are *mostly* compatible, there might be some smaller bugs when trying to use this.

Comment: Aren't you getting `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list` anyway?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ This is Python, not JavaScript or other programming languages like it.

Comment: @KevinGuan oh yeah, dammit

Comment: `print` is a function in nowadays Python.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Nope, it's a function in Python 3, but it's still a statement  in Python 2. Note that some people are still using Python 2.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I am still working in 2.7; Should change that I know :/

Comment: @JeD: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​DAMMIT ALL TEH THINGZ...but we really should test the code before post it as an answer right? :)

Comment: It's not that the code is incorrect, @Kevin. It's just that it's written for Python 2.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Well, that's correct then. Since this question isn't *version special*, I think Python 2 code or Python 3 code isn't an important point.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt But it'll usually work just fine in Python2 with the parentheses as well. You run the risk of inadvertently creating a tuple though. `from __future__ import print_function` if you want to be on the safe side.